# How to incorporate or implement a DOM API to v8?

Tags: javascript, c++, dom, v8

I am writing a server application that is able to manipulate the DOM before it is served to the client.

I am using C++ and Google's v8 as a javascript engine but I don't see any DOM API in v8.

Is there an open source implementation for doing DOM manipulation on HTML?
If not how would you implement one?

Comment: @Luke CplusplusDOM was the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM is created and linked to the V8 engine in Chrome. The V8 sources know nothing about the browser DOM. The quickest way to get this working for you would be to try to extract the parts of Chrome (Chromium, really) that load HTML into a structure, and the parts that link the DOM and DOM methods into V8. It's probably not as bad as you think. If anything, Google produces pretty clean C++, as far as I can tell from looking at the V8 source code. It's probably not as bad as you think.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out [CplusplusDOM](http://code.google.com/p/es-operating-system/wiki/CplusplusDOM)? (which has been created after your question was asked)

> The C++ DOM API is a library for writing Web applications in C++ over NPAPI/Pepper using the Web IDL C++ binding  for accessing DOM objects inside the Web browser.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have (as I understood) your own dom implementation in C++ and only need JS dom binding, I believe it would be easier to implement most part of it in JS mapping low-level JS functions to interface you already have

Answer (score 0):

Safari/Chrome use the Webkit rendering engine, which incorporates CSS rendering and the DOM, I would say it's one of the best rendering engines in addition to Opera's - I think it could be of use:

http://webkit.org/

Comment: I don't need a full grown rendering engine.
I just need to parse the HTML & CSS into a DOM object and save the output as html.
Is there some kind of solution that I'm seeking or do I have to build it myself?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018, [Cloudflare Workers](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-workers-unleashed/) run on the V8 engine and some devs have been investigating how to access DOM parsing and manipulation. They discovered **[dom-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-parser)** and **[cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)**, so it's possible these might provide what you need. Cheerio provides a helpful jQuery-like syntax. They are NodeJS modules, but it appears that they might be able to run within V8.

See: https://simon-thompson.me/simple-dom-manipulation-via-jquery-in-cloudflare-workers/